# Trying to add navigation highlighting on scroll with javascript/jQuery - Something wrong in figuring out height of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-frontend

I am working on a scrollable portfolio page for Free Code Camp, and I am trying to add navigation highlighting. By this, I mean that I would like to make it so that after I scroll past the top of a section(i.e. from the "home" section to "about" section), the navigation link corresponding to that section should highlight. This part I have actually figured out for the most part. However, there is a bug that I cannot seem to figure out. The change from my portfolio section to my contact section highlights in navigation before I get to the actual section. Could any of you have any idea why this is?

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the fact that I am using the .innerHeight function in javascript, but I am not sure.

Here is the relevant javascript, and I will have a link at the bottom to the codepen.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var navHeight = $('nav').innerHeight();
      var componentEnd = [];


      $('.component').each(function(){
        componentEnd.push($(this).offset().top + $(this).innerHeight() - navHeight);
      });

      $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        var pos = $(document).scrollTop();

        for (var i = 0; i < componentEnd.length; i++) {
          if (pos <= componentEnd[i] ) {
            var index = i;
              break;
          }
        }

        $('.navbar-nav li')
          .removeClass('nav-active')
          .eq(index)
          .addClass('nav-active');
      });
    });
```

[Portfolio Page-Codepen](https://codepen.io/Noble99/full/ZeEMVP/)

If any of you have any thoughts, I'd really appreciate it! I've been working at this for a while now.

Comment: What OS and browser are you using? I can't seem to replicate this on OS X in Chrome or Firefox. Although, in FF it does un-highlight the Contact nav if you scroll all the way to the bottom. Have you taken a look at the outerHeight for jQuery? http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

Comment: Hey, looks great – i think the problem is occuring if you adjust the width of the browser window (technically the viewport) – the responsiveness changes the height of the elements – because you are grabbing the innerHeights on ready it's no longer accurate. you can capture the window resize event and reevaluate the innerheights.

Comment: @Pango Do you think this is an issue of cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: I wasn't sure, I just couldn't get it to replicate so I was trying to figure out if I understood the problem correctly. It looks like it was solved, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out – by capturing the resize event and recalculating the heights the problem goes away.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var navHeight = $('nav').innerHeight();

  $('.navbar-nav li a').click(function (event) {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });

  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': ($target.offset().top - navHeight)
    }, 900, 'swing');
  });

  var componentEnd = [];

  // Create function to run heights whenever required
  function getHeights() {         
    componentEnd = []; // empty old height
    $('.component').each(function(){
      componentEnd.push($(this).offset().top + $(this).innerHeight() - navHeight);
    }); 
  }
  // run heights initially 
  getHeights();

  //capture window rezise
  $( window ).resize(getHeights);

  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var pos = $(document).scrollTop();

    for (var i = 0; i < componentEnd.length; i++) {
      if (pos <= componentEnd[i] ) {
        var index = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    $('.navbar-nav li')
      .removeClass('nav-active')
      .eq(index)
      .addClass('nav-active');
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZZZOw

You have probably noticed the issue comes up following a window resize, which effects the heights of your elements. By capturing resize and placing the innerHeight code into a callable function we can fix the issue.